# Why is my isotope not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

This is what I have and for the life of me I do not get why my isotope isn't working

```js
$( function() {
  
  $('#content').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.background {
 background-color: lightblue;
 width: 1000px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

.tile {
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
}


.x300x300 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 
}

.x300x200 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
}

.x200x200 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}

.x150x100 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  
  <div id="content">
  
   <div class="tile x300x300">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
             <div class="box-text">
                 Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
             </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x300x200">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
  
   
   <div class="tile x200x200">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>   
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x150x100">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x150x100">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x300x300">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x150x100">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x300x200">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
  
   
   <div class="tile x200x200">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x150x100">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="tile x150x100">
    <h2 class="box-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="box-text">
                    Amet dolor? Diam cras ac quis a ut, augue massa cursus natoque cursus in sociis rhoncus, scelerisque mus ac. Pellentesque odio rhoncus, aliquet tempor? Nisi cursus lorem tincidunt penatibus eu scelerisque! Scelerisque mid rhoncus turpis eros? Nunc rhoncus in turpis, mus, nec augue, odio, mid tempor aliquam, ultricies.
                </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
```

So I have my script tags:

```
    <script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
```

However the error I'm getting says:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function controller.js:7(anonymous function) controller.js:7jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.js:433completed jquery-1.9.1.js:103

This is the 7th line: $('#content').isotope({

Why is my isotope function undefined? I have the script and everything.

------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------

Problem sovled, thank you

Comment: Did you try placing the jQuery script first, just to see if that works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery needs to be defined first, otherwise isotope can't extend it.